# How to select using not operation in Scala XML?

Tags: xml, scala

there is a XML example:

```
<grid>
    <row>
        <cell colSpan="1" name="cell1"/>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell name="cell2" flow="horizontal"/>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell name="cell3" flow="horizontal"/>
    </row>
</grid>
```

and this is the part of code that extracts nodes:

```
val file = XML.loadFile(`above xml file's path`)

for (l <- file \\ "something to select nodes that are not cell" ) {
  ....      
}
```

What should I write instead of the selection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This will return all nodes that are *not* named "cell":**

```
file \\ "_" filterNot (_.label == "cell")
```

(it's an "everything" [`\\` projection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.Node) plus a standard `filterNot` call)

Note that the nodes in the resulting `NodeSeq` will have their structure preserved, e.g. the "row" nodes will still have children "cell" nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to select only `row` elements? Do you want to use XPath on the XML?

Anyway, this can be used:

```
import scala.xml._

val root = XML.loadFile("grid.xml")
for (child <- root.child) {
    if (child.label != "cell") {
        println(child.label)
    }
}
```

Each `child` is an instance of [`scala.xml.Node`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/#scala.xml.Node). It supports a lot of navigation methods.